# IcoMoon Font Doubling Up

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, icon-fonts

I figured it wasn't normal that when I employed Icomoon fonts, that they would double up.

So in my case, there would be two of the same icon displayed side by side, whereas I only coded for one. Both icons react the same, if I applied CSS properties like color.

How do I remove one of those icons, so that they don't double up?

Comment: I see to see something in order to help you debug. When you look at the source code, do you see duplicate source code for the fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really quick answer without anything to show/jfiddle - I also got this duplication and got round it by commenting out all classes with '**:before**'

For example:

```
.icon-twitter:before {
    content: "\e002";
}
```

This does get rid of the duplicate but is, imho, a hack. So I'm gonna look into something more suitable and will update this when done.